# ant buildfile + javadoc -- including html in javadoc bottom

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I am trying to modify the ant build file that comes packaged with a java library I am working with so that it will include links in the `javadoc bottom` part of the page. I have the variables
`${author.name}` and `${author.url}`
in the ant build.xml file. The line in question I am trying to edit is the `javadoc bottom="library ${project.name} by ${author.name}."` below

```
<!-- create the java reference of the library -->
<javadoc bottom="library ${project.name} by ${author.name}." 
    classpath="${classpath.local.location}/core.jar;{project.bin}" 
    destdir="${project.tmp}/${project.name}/reference" 
    verbose="false" 
    stylesheetfile="resources/stylesheet.css" 
    doctitle="Javadocs: ${project.name}" 
    public="true" version="false" 
    windowtitle="Javadocs: ${project.name}"      
>
```

Right now, it prints something like this:

*Library myLibrary, by adilapapaya*

I would instead like it to include a link to the author page. E.g. something like

*Library myLibrary, by [adilapapaya](http://adilapapaya.com).*

or even

*Library myLibrary, by adilapapaya, http://adilapapaya.com.*

but I'm not sure how to add a `href` to the ant build file above. I've tried

```
<javadoc bottom="library ${project.name} by <a href=${author.url}>${author.name}</a>."
```

but I get an error saying that I can't do that. Basically, I'm looking for the ant equivalent of

```
<a href=${author.url}>${author.name}</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add a nested `<bottom>` element, like this:

```
<javadoc ... >
  ...
  <bottom>
    <![CDATA[
      library ${project.name} by <a href="${author.url}">${author.name}</a>
    ]]>
  </bottom>
</javadoc>
```

Reference: [Ant javadoc task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html), the first 3 examples show how the "bottom" element is used.